# How to add image that depend on names in birt report?

Tags: birt, eclipse-neon

I want to add image to my report that depend on names.If i choose a name Eg : "Michael", report wiil show up the information about him and his image.Do i have to use dynamic image? Please , give me any advice and Thank you.

Comment: Plesae read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the dynamic images into the BIRT based report, there are many options but mainly used below two options:

1. Images stored into a directory and filename (image name) is dynamically set into the BIRT image control. This could be achieved just by setting the image control value using some SQL record (column from the sql query which stores the image filename)
2. The second and mostly used for adding logos and user faces into reports for printing. In this methodology, images are stored into the database by using BLOB type columns and the SQL query picks the image column and set into the BIRT's Image control dynamically

To select the record for each person, one parameter is to be created which takes input at runtime and determine the person data from the database or other source.

Example, 
Employee table

```
ID                 Name               Adress               Image
1                  Abc                Xyz                  8743ho4orh39hof (binary image)
2                  Def                XXv                  klsjlajerownln3oj3n4jo4
```

Now, we create a parameter which take employee id as input and based upon input the report fetch record from database and render data into report for the employee.

It will be fully dynamic and every details will be loaded dynamically for the employee for which employee id has been passed.